# render form over grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created Form and  Grid Panel in Extjs now i want to display a form over a grid when i click on a "Add Record" button

example

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a modal [Window](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Window). A la..

```
var window = new Ext.Window({
  modal: true,
  items: [ yourFormPanel ]
)};
```

You can put the standard form panel inside of the items in the Window itself (thus the 'yourFormPanel' variable), along with any other configuration options. Once you have everything in the window, you just use the show() method to put the Window on the screen. Which probably would be done from the [button](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Button) handler in this case. Should look something like this.

```
var button = new Ext.Button({
  text: 'Add Record',
  handler: function() { window.show(); }
});
```

That's it!

Comment: Well , if i click again on that button the window doesn't appear ??

Comment: One of the configuration options in Window (link posted above) is closeAction. Set that to 'hide' if you only want one instance of the window ever created and used. Keep in mind that you'll probably need to reset the form after submission so that when the user goes to reopen the window that the old data isn't still sitting in there, too.